# Any better way to declare colours of buttons, backgrounds?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xhtml

Visual studio seems to have a problem with the auto generated code in C# aspx.net

> "Message   2   Validation (XHTML 1.0 Transitional): Attribute 'bgcolor' is considered outdated. A newer construct is recommended.  C:\Users\Anton54\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\WebSite1\Games.aspx  9   7   C:...\WebSite1\"

This is for the background of the website and is auto generated.

Is there any better way to code this?

Comment: Side note: consider switching to newer VS 2013 and using ASP.Net MVC4/5 as it will give you full control over HTML (unlike WebForms with are still here, but provide limited control over generated HTML)

Comment: It's been a while since I worked with VS2008, but I can't remember it doing silly things like add a `bgcolor` attribute and then complaining about it.

Answer (score 3):

It may be working properly if you checking the rendering mode as `Legacy`, which is not advised , about [XHTML Rendering Mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178159%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

```
<system.web>
<!-- other elements here -->
    <xhtmlConformance 
        mode="Legacy" />
</system.web>
```

Now it clearly says it is checking with `Transitional`, which is often happen when we do convert application from `ASP.Net 1.1 to higher version`

Check [HTML attribute bgcolor is deprecated: What To Use Instead?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361633/html-attribute-bgcolor-is-deprecated-what-to-use-instead)

[Also List of deprecated elements still widely in use](http://css-tricks.com/list-of-depreciated-elements-still-in-widespread-use/)

Use a valid [`CSS background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background) property

```
background: namedColor | hexadecimalcolorcode;

background-color:namedColor | hexadecimalcolorcode;
```

Comment: I beleive OP is saying ASP.NET control is adding `bgcolor=""` attribute to control, yet this has been deprecated for many years. (that is to say that the library is adding it [unintentionally]--or maybe I'm misunderstanding)

Comment: +1: Note that that OP uses VS2008, so it is expected that some generated code would be not up to 2014 standards...